# Nginx to load balance deployment inside a service kubernetes

Tags: nginx, deployment, kubernetes

I want to use Nginx to load balance a kubernetes deployment.
The deployment is part of a service. It contains pod which can be scaled. I want NGINX to be part of the service without being scaled.

I know that I can use NGINX as an external load balancer by configuring it with external dns resolver. With that it can get the IP of the pods scaled and apply its own load balanced rules.

Is it possible to make NGINX part of the service? Then how to do the DNS resolution to the pods? In that case, which pods the service name is refered to?

I would like to avoid the declaration of two services to keep a single definition of the setup which represent a microservice.

More generally, how can I declare in a same service:

- a  unit which is scaled
- a backend, not scaled
- a database, not scaled

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can't have NGINX as part of the service. Service doesn't contain any pods, deployment does. It sounds like you want an ingress service, that would be a load balancer any and all services on the cluster

EDIT:

An ingress controller in essence is a deployment of NGINX exposed publicly as a service acting as a load balancer/fan out. The deployment scans your cluster for ingress resources and reconfigures NGINX to forward requests to appropriate services.

Typically people deploy a single controller that acts as the load balancer for all of your microservices. You can fan out based on DNS, URI, other headers and so on. You can also do TLS termination, add basic auth to specific services, it's even possible to splice in NGINX config snippets directly into the ingress resources.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It means that one objective of the service is to hide a set af pods scaled behind a name and a dns in order to allow the load balancing. Is that correct?

Ok, I'm going to have a deepper look on the ingress controller. In the case of I want to deploy, let's say 5 microservices, is it possible to declare 5 different ingress controllers based on NGINX with 5 different strategy/configuration? (caching, load balance..)

Thanks